# Function Triggers even when if statement is false

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local TouchPart = workspace["Start"] 
local target = game.Workspace.Level1


local function teleport()
    TouchPart.Touched:Connect(function(touched)
        if touched.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
            local Player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(touched.Parent)
            if Player then
                    --Player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = target.CFrame + Vector3.new(0, 5, 0)
                    print("Teleport")
            end
        end
    end)
end

while true do
    local zeit = game.Workspace.wall1.time.Value
    zeit = zeit - 1
    game.Workspace.wall1.time.Value = zeit
    game.Workspace.wall1.SurfaceGui.Frame.TextLabel.Text = zeit
    wait(1)
    print(zeit)
    if zeit == 0 then
        teleport()
        game.Workspace.wall1.time.Value = 20
    end
    
end
```

The Function Teleport should only be called if zeit == 0. And print("Teleport") should only work when zeit hits 0 and the player is touching the part.

My Problem is even if zeit isnt 0 the function teleport() prints "Teleport" into the console when a player touches the part. Am i missing something there ?

Comment: If ```0``` never happen in condition because of ```wait(1)``` then try ```if zeit < 1 then``` - By the Way: What Value have ```game.Workspace.wall1.time.Value``` ?

Comment: ...and i bet its better to define ```local zeit``` outside (before) the ```while```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are connecting a Touched listener every time `zeit` reaches zero. This listener will fire from here on out, until you disconnect it. It also means that after two loops, it will print "teleport" twice, and after three you will see it printed three times with every touch.

You either need to disconnect the listener, or simply teleport the people touching the part when the timer strikes zero. Here's how you would do the latter :

```lua
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local TouchPart = workspace["Start"] 
local target = game.Workspace.Level1
local zeit = game.Workspace.wall1.time
local wallText = game.Workspace.wall1.SurfaceGui.Frame.TextLabel

-- function for teleporting all of the players currently touching the TouchPart
local function teleport()
    local touchingPlayers = {}
    local parts = TouchPart:GetTouchingParts()
    for _, touched in ipairs(parts) do
        local Player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(touched.Parent)
        if Player then
            touchingPlayers[Player] = touched.Parent
        end
    end)

    -- teleport all the touching players
    for player, character in pairs(touchingPlayers) do
        print("Teleporting " .. player.Name)
        -- character:PivotTo(target.CFrame + Vector3.new(0, 5, 0))
    end
end

-- keep the wall text constantly updated
zeit.Changed:Connect(function(newValue)
    wallText.Text = tostring(newValue)
end)

-- update the counter every second
while wait(1) do
    zeit.Value -= 1
    if zeit.Value == 0 then
        teleport()
        wait(1)
        zeit.Value = 20
    end
end
```